# Как обрезать строку после _ при помощи js regexp?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:

> total_photography_1990_1994

Нужно:

1. обрезать строку после _ включительно с _ ;
   если в строке 2 _ то обрезать после 2го
2. после _ забирать цифры и записывать в переменную;
   если в втроке 2 _ то забирать после 2го

Пробую так:

```
let prName = projectName.substring(0, projectName.indexOf('_'));
```

но в таком случае обрежет сразу после первого _ , как учесть, что может быть 2 _?

в результате хочу получить две переменные:

1. total photography
2. 1990-1994

Comment: /([(\D+_\D+)|(\D+)]+?)_(\d+_\d+)/g может так? соотвественно в 1-й группе текст, во 2-й цифры и в них замените _, если надо на пробел или дефис

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = 'total_photography_1990_1994';
let arr= str.match(/[\D]+(?=[\_])|[\d]+_?[\d]+/g);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: супер! спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

[str.lastIndexOf();](http://javascript.ru/string/lastindexof)

```
let prName = projectName.substring(0, projectName.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

на счет цифр

```
let nums = projectName.substring(projectName.lastIndexOf('_')+1);
//убераем из результата все кроме цифр
nums = nums.replace(/[^0-9]/gim,'');
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ!
мне больше подошел вариант Александра выше, я в итоге получаю массив с двумя значениями с которыми уже можно работать удобно